# Why does Realm use RealmOptional<Int> rather than Int? for optional properties?

Tags: swift, realm

Realm's [documentation on optional properties](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#optional-properties) states:

> `String`, `NSDate`, and `NSData` properties can be declared as optional or non-optional using the standard Swift syntax. Optional numeric types are declared using [`RealmOptional`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/RealmOptional.html).

Why do numeric types use the non-standard `RealmOptional` rather than Swift's built-in optional syntax?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Realm model classes automatically implement getters and setters for your persisted properties that access the underlying database data. In order to provide these getters and setters, your properties must be declared with the `dynamic` modifier. This modifier asks Swift to dynamically dispatch accesses to the properties via getters and setters rather than directly accessing the member at compile time. The `dynamic` modifier comes with a significant limitation: it is only supported for types that can be represented in Objective-C. This is because Swift's dynamic dispatch is built on top of the Objective-C runtime. It is this limitation that prevents `Int?` from being directly supported by Realm.

You may wonder how `String?`, `NSData?`, and `NSDate?` are supported given this limitation. The answer is that they have natural equivalents in Objective-C, namely `nullable NSString *`, `nullable NSData *`, and `nullable NSDate *`. No such equivalents exist for Swift's numeric types.