# Realm model contains property but not found it at runtime

Tags: ios, realm, swift4, realm-database

I am getting error as below

> Invalid property name , reason: 'Property 'IsRecordDeleted' not found in object of type 'MyCustomModel'

Where as my Model is as Under

```
@objcMembers public class MyCustomModel : Object {
dynamic var   Id : String = ""
dynamic var   ProductId : String? = ""
dynamic var   IsRecordDeleted : Bool? = false
dynamic var   ProductBarcode : String? = ""


override public class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "Id"
}
```

}

and I am making query like this :

```
let mSavedItems = mDbHelper.realmObj.objects(MyCustomModel.self).filter("IsRecordDeleted = false")
```

What could be problem here. I do not know why my app is crashing with the same error. But If I change the value like

```
    let mSavedItems = mDbHelper.realmObj.objects(MyCustomModel.self).filter("ProductId = 0")
```

The app gets run, but crashed on when I use IsRecordDeleted in predicate.

Please tell me what could be problem

Comment: iirc properties on a Realm object can only be of types that can be represented in Objective-C. `Bool?` cannot. Does it have to be optional? This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/33356943/7292964

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
let mSavedItems = mDbHelper.realmObj.objects(MyCustomModel.self)
let filtered = mSavedItems.filter { $0.IsRecordDeleted == false }
```

and

```
let mSavedItems = mDbHelper.realmObj.objects(MyCustomModel.self) 
let filtered = mSavedItems.filter { $0.ProductId == "0" }
```

For both

```
let mSavedItems = mDbHelper.realmObj.objects(MyCustomModel.self) 
let filtered = mSavedItems.filter {
   $0.IsRecordDeleted == false 
   && $0.ProductId == "0" 
}
```

//

```
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ProductId == '0' AND IsRecordDeleted == false")
let filtered = mSavedItems.filter(resultPredicate)
```

Comment: Why I need to do $0 ??

Comment: its not recognizing the $0.ProductId, or if I put them in "" the app crashes

Comment: it give me error in xcode >>  Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure

Comment: thought it caused a glitch with you , i think it should work try it again

Comment: how can I try when Xcode is not allowing me to run the code

Comment: which version ??

Comment: well I do not know I just installed it using cocoapod

Comment: It helped, 2 questions more, What is this way called of writing predicate, and Yes also please write Predicate in string so that I can learn both ways

Comment: can I ask 1 last thing?

Comment: I have some items saved in the DB, I am showing them In the TableView, and when I get One Item from table, and Wants to update its some properties then this gives me error on updating. Where as when I make that Items copy in simple structure form and then I try to update it gets update

Comment: can't help without knowing the error , make sure it's not the primary key as it always happen with Realm , also use **mDbHelper.realmObj.beginWrite()** if you have multiple updates

Comment: well I do not have multiple updates, As i told you that I just try to update single Item

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find that simply switching to filter blocks instead of string predicates might stop the crash, but will not produce the expected results.

This is because `IsRecordDeleted` never gets saved to the database. It is not a type that can be represented in Objective-C, therefore it cannot be `dynamic`, so Realm ignores it.

Take as an example the following class:

```
@objcMembers class MyObject: Object {
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var testBool: Bool? = false

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

And say we initialize them like this:

```
    let obj1 = MyObject()
    obj1.id = "1"
    obj1.testBool = true

    let obj2 = MyObject()
    obj2.id = "2"
    obj2.testBool = false

    let realm = try? Realm()
    try? realm?.write {
        realm?.add(obj1, update: true)
        realm?.add(obj2, update: true)
    }
```

If we query Realm for these objects using `realm.objects(MyObject.self)`, you'll get something like this

```
Results<MyObject> <0x7fe410c0ad90> (
    [0] MyObject {
        id = 1;
    },
    [1] MyObject {
        id = 2;
    }
)
```

And you'll see that in the database, there indeed is no property named `testBool`, which was our optional `Bool`.

You can easily see that the optional `Bool` may cause problems if you write it out like this instead:

```
class MyObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = ""
    @objc dynamic var testBool: Bool? = false   // This line will not compile.

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

I'm curious why the `IsRecordDeleted` needs to be optional in the first place, since it seems to have a value from the get-go. If it doesn't, then something like this will work as expected:

```
@objcMembers public class MyCustomModel: Object {
    dynamic var Id: String = ""
    dynamic var ProductId: String? = ""
    dynamic var IsRecordDeleted: Bool = false
    dynamic var ProductBarcode: String? = ""


    override public class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "Id"
    }
}
```

and you can query via string like you were trying to do in the first place.

If it *has* to be optional, then Realm provides a `RealmOptional` for this exact case, that you can look into [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/RealmOptional.html).

Comment: why cant we make things optional ? and why it is not saved in the Realm. ??

Comment: This answer explains a little more in depth: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33358225/7292964 but basically, your properties need to be marked `dynamic` and for that, they need to be exposed to Objective-C. There is no Objective-C equivalent of an optional `Bool`, `Int`, `Double`, etc.