# Bool and Int properties not added to Realm

Tags: realm, swift5

I'm using `Realm` with `Codeable`. I noticed that `Bool` & `Int` attributes aren't added to the table in `Realm Browser` as shown in ScreenShot.
How to fix this issue? 
[image]

Comment: Bool and Int properties can not be declared as optional in Realm. Only "String, NSDate, and NSData properties can be declared as optional" - from the Realm documentation. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59323939/10706839

Comment: @lajosdeme hmm **Storing optional numbers is done using RealmOptional.** For example `let age = RealmOptional<Int>()` which is an optional Int.

Comment: It's a good idea an best practice here on SO to post code and models as text, not screenshots. That way we can copy and past if we need to use them in an answer instead of retyping. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make optional int's and bool's in Realm, they must be defined as [RealmOptional](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#supported-types).

So update your model like this

```
@objcMembers class CategoryDoc: Object: Codeable {
    dynamic var name: String?

    let isActive = RealmOptional<Int>()
    let v = RealmOptional<Bool>()
```